# VBA convert numbers stored as text to numbers on cell change

Tags: vba, excel

Using the below code to convert numbers stored as text to numbers. How would i automate this macro to trigger on cell changes?

eg. as soon as i paste data onto the spreadsheet from another source, I want the newly pasted cells within range Y:Y to convert numbers stored as text to numbers

Have tried a few different things, but the cells are only converted when set the macro to run manually.

```
Sub macro()

Range("Y:Y").Select 
With Selection
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the code below to your Worksheet's module, to the `Worksheet_Change` event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Y:Y")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Target
        .NumberFormat = "0"

        If InStr(.Value, "`") = 1 Then ' if leading character is apostrophe
            .Value = Mid(.Value, 2) ' start from second character
        Else ' regular number
            .Value = .Value
        End If
    End With
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Shai, but this still didn't work. to add to my original comment, this is when copied numerical data contains a leading apostrophe and so is not usable for further mathmatical equations or lookups. would a remove characters function be more appropriate here?

Comment: @brittd try edited code to remove the leading apostrophe

Comment: same issue in that it doesn't seem to trigger......would specifying the range of cells that have been pasted, as opposed to the whole column fix this?

Comment: @brittd are you sure you put the code in the right worksheet module ?

Comment: Absolutely. Worksheet_change. The only thing that has worked was the original manual macro. To give further background, multiple rows of data is pasted from another workbook, to columns A:AD. Column Y will be needed for further lookups, but the values are numbers stored as text (have the proceeding apostrophe) and so need to be converted.

Comment: Replace `If InStr(.Value, "'") = 1` by `If .PrefixCharacter = "'"`, as the leading apostrophe is not included in `.Value` (and neither in `.Value2` nor `.Text` too).